# Implementing Google connect with openId Connect on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid-connect

I'm trying to write a basic GAE app to test OpenId Connect. It fails with the error in the logs : "insufficient permission" on the people().get(). It seems that this program asks for OpenId credentials and not OAuth (there is a redirect to https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth in the login page url. But this is implicit. How to explicitly ask for OAuth? It is strange as the decorator.has_credentials() returns True with these openId credentials...

```
import logging
import webapp2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
from google.appengine.api import users

decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
  client_id='123456789999.....googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret='ABCDEF.........',
  scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'])


service = build('plus', 'v1')

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_aware
  def get(self):
    if decorator.has_credentials():
        response =service.people().get(userId="me").execute(http=decorator.http())
        # Write the profile data
        self.response.write(unicode(response))
    else:
        url = decorator.authorize_url()
        # Write a page explaining why authorization is needed,
        # and provide the user with a link to the url to proceed.
        # When the user authorizes, they get redirected back to this path,
        # and has_credentials() returns True.
        self.response.write('You must login : <a href="'+url+'">Go</a>')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                           ('/', MainHandler),
                           (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())],
                          debug=True)
```

Comment: It seems as if OpenID 2.0 was used and not OAuth 2 (cf message on the Authorization screen)

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate Google+ API in Google Console http://code.google.com/apis/console.

APIs & Auth / APIs / Google+ API

And click in button with text: "Enable API"